# Angular ng-if isn't hiding if the value is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand why ng-if isn't showing the right content.

```
<div ng-if="user.premium">
     <p>If user.premium is true show this content</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="!user.premium">
     <p>If user.premium is false show this content</p>
</div>
```

This seems to be the way I would expect it to work. I've done a console.log on user.premium and it returns the following data.

```
premium: false;
```

In this instance I would believe that the content to be shown would be the false content.

In this case I'd expect only the true content to show.

```
premium: true;
```

However on both true and false I'm getting the true content showing in my DOM.

How would I go about showing the correct content if the property is true or false.

Comment: Are you sure that 'true' and 'false' are boolean and not strings?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, they are 100% boolean

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/8k580s95/1/

Comment: but `console.log(user.premium)` what does return?

Comment: if you console log `user.premium` you get  `premium: true` or `true`? sorry just to clarify it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've just been a plonker and forgot to add the user to my scope.. Answer below for anyone else being a plonker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been a complete plonker and forgot to add the values to my scope..

The answer is adding `scope.user = user;` to my controller. Yes without the dollar because our set up is odd.

For a proper set up you should use the dollar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution..

make sure "user", it is object in your controller. like this..

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.premium = false; //default value
```

If you can assigned any value to "$scope.user.premium"

```
$scope.user.premium = true; // Or any other value
```

Definitely it will work...

```
<div ng-if="user.premium">
    <p>If user.premium is true show this content</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="!user.premium">
     <p>If user.premium is false show this content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some situations resulting this bug. I try to remark two:

- You may need to manually `$apply` your changes on scope after making it false. This happens when you change a value in scope in in a wrapper which doesn't call for $apply natively.
- You may use the variable scope but you have a variable with the same name in the `$rooScope` or a child scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using As controller(MainController as mainCtrl). You should use 
like this

```
<div ng-if="mainCtrl.user.premium">
     <p>If user.premium is true show this content</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="!mainCtrl.user.premium">
     <p>If user.premium is false show this content</p>
</div>
```